# Can Delphi (CE) 10.4 for iOS work with an iPad that has OS 14?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, delphi, ipad

I've developed an app that is on the AppStore (AnyScale).  I realise that I need to write it for Android and so am looking at Delphi (I've experience with Delphi in the past).  So, I've got Delphi 10.4.2 (Community Edition) working and it can see my iPad.  However, when I try to run it I get a message saying cannot connect to the Mac, even though when I test the connection it works fine.

I've also tried working with the simulator but it says iOS simulator version 11 or later is currently not supported - xCode 13.1 doesn't seem interested in iOS simulators back that far.

So, my question is whether anyone is actually using Delphi productively with xCode 13, Mac M1 chip, iOS 13+.

I appreciate that it is a fairly vague question but I'm really wondering if it is going anywhere!

Many thanks in advance,

Ian

Comment: "I get a message saying cannot connect to the Mac.." That error can be a bit misleading - you need to look at the details in the Messages window (including on the Output tab) to find out exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNottage, I'm now getting the connection OK, but still am unable to get it to run on the simulator or device.  See comment below about the simulator.

Comment: I am referring to when you are attempting to run it on a device. As I say, it would help to know the *exact* details being reported by the IDE, which are usually shown in the Messages window, including on the Output tab

Comment: Thanks again @DaveNottage.  I think there is something strange that may be related, but I now have lost the preview in SwiftUI...  I'll have to focus on fixing that before trying anything else.  I'm concerned that my attempts with Delphi may have something to do with it.

Comment: I ended up with a broken Xcode that took a while to fix.  Thanks for the responses @DaveNottage, but I've decided to abandon Delphi and work in Xcode and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, Community Editions are limited just in the features and tools you use, it does not restrict the supporting platforms and according to this [link](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page) it supports your desired OS as well.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I added an iPhone 5s (iOS 11.4) to XCode and set that as the target.   A message box comes up with a message, part of which is "The following error was returned 'iOS Simulator version 11 or later is currently not supported."  That seems pretty clear to me, but I do appreciate that I may be missing something.

Comment: I've put a comment on the previous message - I've abandoned Delphi!